# Clients connected to Cisco router can't access to internet

Tags: cisco, routing, internet

I'm currently undergoing CCNa academy so I got a "job" from my boss to configure Cisco 871 router.  Unfortunately we just finished first semester at academy so there are some things that I'm still having hard time to understand.

I managed to configure router so it connect to internet or to be exact it has internet access through  another adsl modem that is in bridge mode.

Here is picture of setup

http://www.pohrani.com/f/3m/EI/gxiOrOu/network.jpg

The problem is that users are not able to use internet when connected to this router.  I'm able to access router through telnet  ( ip 192.168.13.10)  but that's it.

Here is the config from router 
http://pastebin.com/8JaMmqdT

192.168.13.0 255.255.255.128 is network that we use at work.  192.168.13.5 is IP address that is assigned to zyxel adsl modem ( If I'm correct, we could have used any address here since we are connecting this directly to router ? )

Zyxel adsl modem  is connected to FA4 port on Cisco router.   LAN cable is connected to FA0 port and from there it goes to switch ( it's some  asus switch with 50 ports).

Here is routing table

```
Router-Cisco#show ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is 192.168.13.5 to network 0.0.0.0

              192.168.13.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
      S       192.168.13.5/32 is directly connected, Dialer1
      C       192.168.13.0/25 is directly connected, Vlan1
              172.29.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
      C       172.29.252.89 is directly connected, Dialer1
              93.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
      C       93.139.143.80 is directly connected, Dialer1
              10.0.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
      C       10.10.10.0 is directly connected, Loopback0
      S*      0.0.0.0/0 [1/0] via 192.168.13.5
```

And here is IP interface brief

```
Router-Cisco#show ip interface brief
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
Dialer0                    unassigned      YES manual administratively down down   
Dialer1                    93.139.143.80   YES IPCP   up                    up     
FastEthernet0              unassigned      YES unset  up                    up     
FastEthernet1              unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down   
FastEthernet2              unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down   
FastEthernet3              unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down   
FastEthernet4              unassigned      YES manual up                    up     
Loopback0                  10.10.10.100    YES manual up                    up     
Virtual-Access1            unassigned      YES unset  up                    up     
Vlan1                      192.168.13.10   YES manual up                    up
```

If I ping google dns from router e.g. ping 8.8.8.8 it works.  If I ping www.google.com it doesn't work.
Also I'm able to access router via 192.168.13.10 but if I use router as default gateway then I'm not able to access the internet.
Can anyone point me in right direction here or tell me what I missed out ?

p.s. 
From where is network 
 172.29.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
      C       172.29.252.89 is directly connected, Dialer1
comming from ?  I cleared router config before starting and I don't remember configuring this one or that we use something like this at work.

Comment: you say if you ping 8.8.8.8 it works? Does this work on the client PC's to, do they reply to 8.8.8.8? Not the state the obvious, but could be a DNS issue if so.

Comment: Hi, No. From client PC's nothing works except pinging 192.168.13.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done a lot, but there are still a few things to correct.

- **Change the IP address on your modem to something not in the 192.168.13.0/25 range.**

The modem's IP address should only be used for configuration and not for routing.

- **Ensure that `ip routing` has been set. (It's not visible in the running-config).**
- **Remove the 3 ip routes:**

Replace the first one (the default) with a route towards `Dialer1` (your WAN interface): `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer1`.

The second one might not even work as Dialer1 is a PPP interface. And for the last one, 192.168.13.10 is on Vlan1.

- **Change the DHCP default-router:**

Use the ip address of `Vlan1`, `192.168.13.10`.

- **Remove `ip nat outside` from Fa4:**

Having it on `Dialer1` should be enough.

- **Add NAT configuration:**

`ip nat inside source list 10 interface Dialer1 overload` and `access-list 10 permit 192.168.13.0 0.0.0.128`.

That should be enough.

You might also take a look at [this configuration](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/8193) or [this one](http://olivier.cochard.me/reseaux/cisco/exemple-cisco-831-avec-pppoe) to have a broader picture.

And regarding `172.29.252.89`, it might a server address within the ISP network, pushed with PPP/IPCP.

Comment: Hi, this helped. Although I had to  use acess-list 10 permit any. If I used 192.168.13.0 0.0.0.128 then for some strange reason I didn't had internet access.   Now I'm facing another thing and that is very slow connection.  The connection should be around 4Mbps and I get only 0.6Mbps.  I tried setting bandwith on dialer 1 but same thing persists. show interface info ->  http://pastebin.com/7zBMaYJH   show ip nat statistic -> http://pastebin.com/GkwpAueh  and ip nat translations -> http://pastebin.com/rEZ6G4TT  Also I tried int vlan 1

ip tcp adjust-mss 1452

ip mtu 1492 but it didnt help